# Wordpress PHP - Two values from a theme option

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been working on this for a while now, and have not been able to find an answer anywhere else online.

In my options panel of wordpress, I have an textarea that I can type in, and if I want to add another textarea, I just click to add and remove them.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Theme Options Example]

All my textarea options are put into an array, and I can call them at any time.

What I want to do, and have been trying to figure out for a while now is this:
I want to be able to add a text input below each one of the textareas, and whenever I update it, it put each of the text inputs into an array.

I have a feeling this is just something so simple that I havent thought of yet. If not, please let me know.

Here is github of the options panel: https://github.com/leemason/NHP-Theme-Options-Framework

Below is the code I have been working on:

This code is in a new file called `field_multi_textarea.php` that I have added to a new folder called `multi_text` inside the `fields` directory in the the options folder.

```
<?php
class NHP_Options_multi_textarea extends NHP_Options{   

    /**
     * Field Constructor.
     *
     * Required - must call the parent constructor, then assign field and value to vars, and obviously call the render field function
     *
     * @since NHP_Options 1.0.5
    */
    function __construct($field = array(), $value ='', $parent){

        parent::__construct($parent->sections, $parent->args, $parent->extra_tabs);
        $this->field = $field;
        $this->value = $value;
        //$this->render();

    }//function



    /**
     * Field Render Function.
     *
     * Takes the vars and outputs the HTML for the field in the settings
     *
     * @since NHP_Options 1.0.5
    */
    function render(){

        $class = (isset($this->field['class']))?$this->field['class']:'large-text';

        echo '<ul id="'.$this->field['id'].'-ul">';

        if(isset($this->value) && is_array($this->value)){
            foreach($this->value as $k => $value){
                if($value != ''){

                    echo '<li><div class="fadeout"><textarea id="'.$this->field['id'].'-'.$k.'" name="'.$this->args['opt_name'].'['.$this->field['id'].'][]" rows="6" class="'.$class.'" />'.esc_attr($value).'</textarea></div> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nhp-opts-multi-textarea-remove">'.__('Remove', 'nhp-opts').'</a></li>';

                }//if

            }//foreach
        }else{

            echo '<li><div class="fadeout"><textarea id="'.$this->field['id'].'" name="'.$this->args['opt_name'].'['.$this->field['id'].'][]" rows="6" value="'.$this->field['std'].'" class="'.$class.'" />'.esc_attr($value).'</textarea></div> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nhp-opts-multi-textarea-remove">'.__('Remove', 'nhp-opts').'</a></li>';

        }//if

        echo '<li style="display:none;"><div class="fadeout"><textarea id="'.$this->field['id'].'" name="" rows="6" class="'.$class.'" /></textarea></div> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nhp-opts-multi-textarea-remove">'.__('Remove', 'nhp-opts').'</a></li>';

        echo '</ul>';

        echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nhp-opts-multi-textarea-add" rel-id="'.$this->field['id'].'-ul" rel-name="'.$this->args['opt_name'].'['.$this->field['id'].'][]">'.__('Add More', 'nhp-opts').'</a><br/>';

        echo (isset($this->field['desc']) && !empty($this->field['desc']))?' <span class="description">'.$this->field['desc'].'</span>':'';

    }//function


    /**
     * Enqueue Function.
     *
     * If this field requires any scripts, or css define this function and register/enqueue the scripts/css
     *
     * @since NHP_Options 1.0.5
    */
    function enqueue(){

        wp_enqueue_script(
            'nhp-opts-field-multi-textarea-js', 
            NHP_OPTIONS_URL.'fields/multi_textarea/field_multi_textarea.js', 
            array('jquery'),
            time(),
            true
        );

    }//function

}//class
?>
```

This is the js that I have named `field_multi_textarea.js` and placed inside the `multi_text` folder.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.nhp-opts-multi-textarea-remove').live('click', function(){
        jQuery(this).prev('.fadeout').val('');
        jQuery(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function(){jQuery(this).remove();});
    });

    jQuery('.nhp-opts-multi-textarea-add').click(function(){
        var new_input = jQuery('#'+jQuery(this).attr('rel-id')+' li:last-child').clone();
        jQuery('#'+jQuery(this).attr('rel-id')).append(new_input);
        jQuery('#'+jQuery(this).attr('rel-id')+' li:last-child').removeAttr('style');
        jQuery('#'+jQuery(this).attr('rel-id')+' li:last-child textarea').val('');
        jQuery('#'+jQuery(this).attr('rel-id')+' li:last-child textarea').attr('name' , jQuery(this).attr('rel-name'));
    });

});
```

I am calling for this function in the NHP-options.php like this:

```
array(
    'id' => 'cf_emailaddress2',
    'type' => 'multi_textarea',
    'title' => __('Contact Form Email Address', 'nhp-opts'),
    'sub_desc' => __('To add more, click add more', 'nhp-opts'),
    'et_url' => 'myurl',
    'std' => get_bloginfo('admin_email') ."",
    'desc' => __('Contact Form Email Address, This is where the form will be sent to.', 'nhp-opts')
    ),
```

I can the make input look like the image below, but its value doesnt save, or it is identical to whatever is in the textarea.

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Tried to replicate your setup, but no luck. Are you sure your working code is complete?

Comment: It seems to be... I have installed this on my theme: https://github.com/leemason/NHP-Theme-Options-Framework .. and I added a new folder in the fields directory called `multi_textarea`.. I named the file itself `field_multi_textarea.php` and the js `field_multi_textarea.js`. And I have the js to hide and show the div `fadeout` instead of li text... and in the NHP-options.php, I am calling this by `type => 'multi_textarea`

Comment: This info belongs in the body of the Question. ::::: **I also** added NHP to the theme: **1)** used `get_template_part('nhp', 'options');` as per docs. A bunch of menus appear. **2)** Added your code to `functions.php`, nothing happens. **3)** Instantiated the class, nothing. **4)** Enabled `$this->render()` from the class, it prints the stuff breaking the admin layout. **5)** Conclusion: you are not providing all the code to replicate the issue, hence it is impossible to answer....

Comment: thanks for letting me know. I updated my answer with alot more of my code. I'm confused about the `$this->render()` function though?

Comment: When you clone an input or multiple inputs make sure you check their IDs are not same. Use firebug to check your new inputs and their IDs. It seems to me that your IDs are same in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Check your TextArea field names. I guess they are the same, when saving how you accessing fields
see this below line for name formation

```
echo '<li><div class="fadeout"><textarea id="'.$this->field['id'].'-'.$k.'" name="'.$this->args['opt_name'].'['.$this->field['id'].'][]" rows="6" class="'.$class.'" />'.esc_attr($value).'</textarea></div> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nhp-opts-multi-textarea-remove">'.__('Remove', 'nhp-opts').'</a></li>';
```

similar to taxtarea id you may need to add $k as a prefix.